# How to execute a code from a python module in vscode?

Tags: python, python-module, nba-api

Hello I'm trying to execute a code but it just doesn't react at all

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import shotchartdetail

response = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(
    team_id=0,
    player_id=201935,
    season_nullable='2018-19',
    season_type_all_star='Regular Season'
)

content = json.loads(response.get_json())
```

I'm following a tutorial but I'm lost of how to make this code do something

Comment: what do you want it to do

Comment: This code doesn’t appear to attempt to output anything.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I just followed a tutorial, I thought I would had an output from it. https://datavizardry.com/2020/01/28/nba-shot-charts-part-1/comment-page-1/?unapproved=22&moderation-hash=99b579142d30ea04c68253075887b291#comment-22

Comment: You need to follow the rest of the tutorial, you only copied the first section.

Comment: There's basically not much left